Converting XTEA implementation from JS to Go
I'm trying to rewrite this implementation of XTEA from JS into Go:
function decipherXTea(v, k) {
    const ROUNDS = 32;
    const DELTA = 0x9E3779B9;

    let y = v[0];
    let z = v[1];
    let sum = DELTA * ROUNDS;
    for (let round = 0; round < ROUNDS; round++) {
        z -= ((y << 4 ^ y >> 5) + y) ^ (sum + k[sum >> 11 & 3]);
        sum -= DELTA;
        y -= ((z << 4 ^ z >> 5) + z) ^ (sum + k[sum & 3]);
    }
    return [
        y,
        z
    ];
}

For some reason, my Go code seems to get the same initial y and z values, though after the rounds have completed, the result does not match what my Go code gets at all.
My Go implementation:
func decrypt(k [4]int64, block []byte) []byte {
    y := int64(int32(block[0])<<24 | int32(block[1])<<16 | int32(block[2])<<8 | int32(block[3])<<0)
    z := int64(int32(block[4])<<24 | int32(block[5])<<16 | int32(block[6])<<8 | int32(block[7])<<0)
    fmt.Printf("y: %d, z: %d\n", y, z)

    const (
        rounds       = 32
        delta  int64 = 0x9E3779B9
    )

    sum := delta * rounds
    for i := 0; i < rounds; i++ {
        z -= int64(int32(int64(int32(y)<<4^int32(y)>>5)+y) ^ int32(sum+k[int32(sum)>>11&3]))
        sum -= delta
        y -= int64((int32(z<<4^z>>5) + int32(z)) ^ int32(sum+k[int32(sum)&3]))
    }

    fmt.Printf("result: %d, %d\n", y, z)

    end := make([]byte, 8)
    end[0] = byte(y >> 24 & 255)
    end[1] = byte(y >> 16 & 255)
    end[2] = byte(y >> 8 & 255)
    end[3] = byte(y & 255)

    end[4] = byte(z >> 24 & 255)
    end[5] = byte(z >> 16 & 255)
    end[6] = byte(z >> 8 & 255)
    end[7] = byte(z & 255)

    return end
}


Are you sure the JS result is correct?

I had difficulties following your casts int64(int32(int64(int32(.... This seem to give the same results as golang.org/x/crypto/xtea and is basically your solution:
func decrypt(k [4]uint32, block []byte) []byte {
    y := uint32(block[0])<<24 | uint32(block[1])<<16 | uint32(block[2])<<8 | uint32(block[3])
    z := uint32(block[4])<<24 | uint32(block[5])<<16 | uint32(block[6])<<8 | uint32(block[7])

    const (
        rounds        = 32
        delta  uint32 = 0x9E3779B9
    )

    sum := delta
    sum *= rounds
    for i := 0; i < rounds; i++ {
        z -= (y<<4 ^ y>>5 + y) ^ (sum + k[sum>>11&3])
        sum -= delta
        y -= (z<<4 ^ z>>5 + z) ^ (sum + k[sum&3])
    }

    end := make([]byte, 8)
    end[0] = byte(y >> 24)
    end[1] = byte(y >> 16)
    end[2] = byte(y >> 8)
    end[3] = byte(y)

    end[4] = byte(z >> 24)
    end[5] = byte(z >> 16)
    end[6] = byte(z >> 8)
    end[7] = byte(z)

    return end
}

Try it on the Go playground. I would assume the casting introduces errors somewhere. Also keep in mind that XTEA shouldn't be used in modern applications.
